# Database connection constructor: private or public?

Tags: php

If I want to create a connection class, is it OK to have the __construct as private? Or that will prevent users from connecting if there is more than one user at a time? Or I'm doing something that's completely wrong and this connection class should not even exist? (using connection without specific class would be better?)

code:

```
   <?php

class Connection
{     
    private $host = "hostname";
    private $db_name = "somedatabase";
    private $username = "username";
    private $password = "";
    private $conn;

    private function __construct()
 {


        try {
        $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
            echo "Connected Successfully Bro";
        }
  catch(PDOException $exception) 
  {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}


?>
```

Comment: Please add a little more information about your app, are you using a framework?

Comment: I just try to study PHP (and coding in general) myself, and I'm trying to create a user login system that includes some basic functions of it: Forgot password, email verification and login/logout

Answer (score 0):

If you make the constructor private, only methods within that class will be able to create an instance of it.

That's useful if you are implementing the Singleton pattern (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern), or if you are creating a factory class for example.

The code you provided shows the class not having any other methods, so a private constructor is going to render the class useless if that's the case.

In short, if you need to instantiate the "Connection" class from code outside of the class itself, use a public constructor.

Comment: Got it! And I just tried to do what you said (calling it from outside, and it didn't work) so it has to be public in my case!